# How to grant FTP access to just 1 directory (and its subdirectories) to an account

Tags: permissions, ftp, webserver

Is it possible to give someone FTP access to just one directory (and its subdirectories) and not all the directories of the webserver?

Comment: What is the server program/OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as your FTP Server software supports it (99.9% will).

Generally you should be able to configure folder-specific access in the "user management" section.

Just remember, that if you deny access to the root of the server, the user will not be able to access the sub-folders.

That is:
CORRECT SETUP:

FTP_ROOT_FOLDER -- > Grant access to all

----> FTP_FOLDER_1 --> Grant access to user1

----> FTP_FODLER_2 --> Grant access to user2

INCORRECT SETUP:

FTP_ROOT_FOLDER --> No access

----> FTP_FOLDER_1 --> Grant access to user1

----> FTP_FOLDER_2 --> Grant access to user2

INCORRECT SETUP:

FTP_ROOT_FOLDER --> Grant access to all

----> FTP_FOLDER_1 --> Deny access to user1

---------> SUB_FOLDER_1 --> Grant access to user1

Comment: May be I didn't get it properly, but in your "correct setup" you're giving access to Root folder to all, doesn't that "all" include "user1", "user2"? What I wanted was user1 shouldn't be able to access root but just the "folder_1"

Comment: When I say Grant All to root, it's a personal preference. The idea is that all users can see the listing of folders available, but access to the actual folders is limited. I've found that this makes things alot easier for users, unless you are willing to setup folder aliases for specific users.

Comment: Yeah, I think that I got, but what I'm still confused about is this line: "FTP_ROOT_FOLDER -- > Grant access to all" doesn't this mean that even user1 and user2 are getting access to "FTP_ROOT_FOLDER"